# Chebyshev's inequality and probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$ is a RV and I know E[$X$] = $a$, Var($X$) = $b$. I need to find a $x$ such that [$X$ > $x$] > 0.95, using Chebyshev theorem.

What I did so far: Using Chebyshev, I found [|$X$ - $a$| ⩾ $\sqrt{b^2/0.05}$] ⩽ 0.05. But then after that I am not sure how to get a $x$ for which [$X$ > $x$] > 0.95?

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb P\left [ |X-a| \ge b \right ] \le 0,05$ we use that the set $\{|X-a| \ge b\}$ consists of ${X-a \ge b}$ and $\{a-X \ge b\}$. This means that $\mathbb P[X>a+b] = \mathbb P[X-a >b] \le \mathbb P\left [ |X-a| \ge b \right ] \le 0,05$

Comment: @Lukas: thanks a lot, I understand! So that means, I have now a value  +  for which ℙ[ >  + ] ≤ 0.05. But I need ℙ[ > ] > 0.95. I guess I can write 1 - ℙ[ >  + ] > 0.95. From there, is there a way to get a  such that 1 - ℙ[ >  + ] = ℙ[ > ]?

Comment: Oh, sorry - I misread your post. For that you can use that $\mathbb P[X \le a-b] = \mathbb P[a-X \ge b] \le \mathbb P[|X-a| \ge b] \le 0.05$ and therefore $1-\mathbb P[X \le a-b] = \mathbb P[X> a-b] > 0.95$.